# How to get pathvariables from a REST URL?

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, path-variables

I have the URL path

```
/customer/7854/order/125
```

How do I get the `customerID` `7854`  and the `orderID` `125`?
Currently I'm handling this by splitting the complete string but I don't like it.

Are there alternatives?

Comment: What are you using to set up the endpoint? Spring MVC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you using Spring REST, you can use @PathVariable("id") long id. eg for multiple params:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ex/foos/{fooid}/bar/{barid}")
@ResponseBody
public String getPathValues
  (@PathVariable long fooid, @PathVariable long barid) {
    return "Get a specific Bar with id=" + barid + " from a Foo with id=" + fooid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said in the comments, you're using Spring MVC.

Luckily for you, it provides a really nice way of mapping URL parameters to values!

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{bookmarkId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

As you can see, on the action, you can specify the `bookmarkId`. And then you specify the parameter..

```
Bookmark readBookmark(@PathVariable Long bookmarkId)
```

And now you can access `bookmarkId` as if it was any other value.

**Edit**

So the whole thing together, taken from the examples, would look like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{bookmarkId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
Bookmark readBookmark(@PathVariable String userId, @PathVariable Long bookmarkId) {
    this.validateUser(userId);
    return this.bookmarkRepository.findOne(bookmarkId);
}
```